# Carrying Array Accross Multiple Angular Functions

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope, scope

I'm trying to implement a way for my program to keep track of filters the user has selected and searched through.  The input will be in a text-box, multiple text boxes.  I have a textbox for each option (TimeStamp, SourceHost, UUID, etc)  [I'm building an internal application].  I need to be able to carry the filter list for my parameters and I decided to use an Array object but I am having some issues.  I initialize my array but cannot access the information in other functions

```
app.controller("AppCtrl", function($http, $scope){
    var app= this;
    $scope.filterList = [];
    $scope.filterList.push("test");
    console.log($scope.filterList);
    $scope.incData = function(page, filterList){
        callingIrrelevantFunction(page)
        console.log($scope.filterList);
```

The first console.log outputs "test".  But when I use it later on (this isn't my intended use case I just wanted to make sure I could scope an array and call it inside of function) the output isn't correct.  The actual intended use case is that I will be appending it to the end of the url.

Edit:
Here is a shareable version of my code:

```
app.controller("AppCtrl", function($http, $scope){
   var app = this;
   $scope.filterList = [];
   $scope.filterList.push("uuid=9022");
   $scope.filterList.push("source_host=Kani");

   function foobar(filterList){
       console.log("inside foobar");
       console.log(filterList);
   }
   foobar($scope.filterList);
});
```

Outputs "[]".

Edit #2:

When change my code to just an array, without "$scope." in front of it, the code works.  But I believe I do need the "$scope." for it to work with angular directives.

Comment: from your code. i can't see why your array wouldn't have the same content. you may have other functions tempering the content. part of the code that is not displayed here.

Comment: Echoing @DayanMorenoLeon, can you post your entire controller?

Comment: What changes `callingIrrelevantFunction(page)` made to  $scope.filterList?.

Comment: Why are you assigning strings to `$scope.filterList.push` in your 'shareable' version?

Comment: @Tacoman667 I believe that was my error and I over looked it, thank you for pointing that out.  I believe everything is working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are assigning string values to `$scope.filterList.push` in your 'shareable' version. You are never actually pushing the values into the array.